# How to have a square shaped widget in a row with multiple widgets in Flutter

Tags: flutter, ui-design

I am trying to put some widgets in a row where the first widget should be **square shaped** and use the intrinsic width and height to modify the smaller one of these values so it results in a square shape. The side length should depend on the child widget, which is in my case a Text. Padding the text equally from all sides does not look right. I already tried achieving this with the `AspectRatio` widget and its working as far as it results in the expected square shape, but it does not use the minimal space but rather scales up as much as possible.

Any idea how to get this result without hardcoding the width and height?

[image]

example code

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            SizedBox(height: 100),
            Text('    current status:'),
            SizedBox(height: 5),
            Row(
              children: [
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.red.shade300,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue),
                  ),
                  child: const Center(
                    child: Text(
                      'square',
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(width: 10),
                Flexible(
                  child: Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.blue.shade200,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                      border: Border.all(color: Colors.red),
                    ),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          'placeholder for other widgets',
                          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodySmall,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 50),
            Text('    I want this:'),
            SizedBox(height: 5),
            Row(
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  height: 50,
                  child: AspectRatio(
                    aspectRatio: 1,
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.red.shade300,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                        border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue),
                      ),
                      child: Center(
                        child: Text(
                          'square',
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(width: 10),
                Flexible(
                  child: Container(
                    height: 50,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.blue.shade200,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                      border: Border.all(color: Colors.red),
                    ),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          'placeholder for other widgets',
                          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodySmall,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

EDIT:

my code looks like this now

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final GlobalKey _key = GlobalKey();
  double boxWidth = 0.0;

  final String inputText = 'square';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      setState(() {
        BuildContext? keyContext = _key.currentContext;
        if (keyContext != null) {
          RenderBox renderBox = keyContext.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
          boxWidth = renderBox.size.width;
        }
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            const SizedBox(height: 100),
            Text('    input: $inputText'),
            const SizedBox(height: 50),
            const Text('    with StatefulWidget'),
            const SizedBox(height: 10),
            Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  key: _key,
                  height: boxWidth,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.red.shade300,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue),
                  ),
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text(
                      inputText,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(width: 10),
                Flexible(
                  child: Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    height: boxWidth,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.blue.shade200,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                      border: Border.all(color: Colors.red),
                    ),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          'placeholder for other widgets',
                          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodySmall,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 50),
            const Text('    with AspectRatio'),
            const SizedBox(height: 10),
            Row(
              children: [
                Flexible(
                  flex: 2,
                  child: AspectRatio(
                    aspectRatio: 1,
                    child: Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.red.shade300,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                        border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue),
                      ),
                      child: Center(
                        child: Text(
                          inputText,
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(width: 10),
                Flexible(
                  flex: 8,
                  child: Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.blue.shade200,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                      border: Border.all(color: Colors.red),
                    ),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          'placeholder for other widgets',
                          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodySmall,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is how the different solution approaches behave:
[image: different solution approaches gif]

Comment: please add your code too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using flexible and aspect ratio

```dart
Row(
 children : [
   Flexible(
     flex: 2,
     child: AspectRatio(
      aspectRatio: 1,
      Container(
       color: Colors.red,
      )
     )
    ),
   Flexible(
    flex: 8,
    child: Text(),
   )
 ]
)
```

You can change the flex value as per your requirement

**Edit**

You can use intrinsic height in a row to set the child to the tallest child

```
​import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {


    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        child: IntrinsicHeight(
            child: Row(children: [
          AspectRatio(aspectRatio: 1, child: Container(color: Colors.red)),
          Flexible(
              child: Text(
                  "djdjdjdhjvc gf\nf bg \nhg hshs\nfjgdhjfhj \n hxhkj \n  fjdjd d \n ejejdj "))
        ])));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this and it's working as long as you know that the size of the square's child does not exceed a certain amount. In my case I want it to scale up and down to the needed amount without hardcoding the flex upfront.

Comment: Can tou explain a bit more please? What do you mean by needed amount here

Comment: I added a gif to the question where you can see how the StatefulWidget solution is changing the size according to the child, be it up or down, whereas the AspectRatio solution remains the same size, no matter the child's size. 
The StatefulWidget solution only uses the minimally needed amount of space. However in the AspectRatio solution, I have to hardcode the size upfront and it will stay at this size even if the child requires more space or doesnt need all of the allocated space.

Comment: Nice one. The proper application of IntrinsicHeight and IntrinsicWidth is precisely what I was missing. Thanks alot.

Comment: The flutter said, IntrinsicHeight is relatively expensive, you should avoid using it. [more information](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IntrinsicHeight-class.html)

Comment: Absolutely right but if it's required then there's no other choice other than using it or defining specific size for widgets

Comment: or change to statefull widget and my aproach.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:

```
GlobalKey _key = GlobalKey();
double boxWidth = 0.0;

    @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();

    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      setState(() {
        final _keyContext = _key.currentContext;
        if (_keyContext != null) {
          final box = _keyContext.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
          boxWidth = box.size.width;
        }
      });
    });
  }
  
      @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  key: _key,
                  height: boxWidth,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.red.shade300,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue),
                  ),
                  child: const Center(
                    child: Text(
                      'square',
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(width: 10),
                Flexible(
                  child: Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    height: boxWidth,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.blue.shade200,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                      border: Border.all(color: Colors.red),
                    ),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          'placeholder for other widgets',
                          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodySmall,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thank you. This works perfectly. By chance, do you also know how to achieve this in a '''StatelessWidget''' ?

Comment: This is not going to work in stateless widget. Because this approach first give the needed sizes to widget in widget tree and then calculate them and do whatever you want with that size. So that is why we need state of the widget.